# How to get rid of fat border in terminal windows?

Tags: terminal, nvidia, drivers, appearance

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCGmG.jpg)

Hello everyone. How can i get rid of this border in terminal windows? It appeared after i failed to recompile kernel and after i uninstalled nvidia drivers.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on superuser.com .

Comment: It looks like the fat border is supposed to be a semi transparent shadow. I guess you either have to install drivers that are compatible with X compositing or disable compositing (which might include switching to a window manager that doesn't require it).